# For cloning purposes, when does serializing outperform cloning?

Tags: java, performance, serialization

Assume the existence of a [graphical model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model) instance which I want to clone it often for processing (a.k.a inference) purposes. I had several issues with poor performence with deep cloning till I used serialization. I was not believing in serialization (as another approach for cloning) till I tried it.

This brings me to the question: When it is advisable to serialize instead of deep clone? is there any threshold or tradeoff I should first examine in order to come up with the choice?

I am trying to comprehend this to advise my students on best practices in such situations.

Comment: Good question, but it could be improved with some concrete benchmarks (explaining and generalizing some experiments should be easier than stating a general criterion). What exactly do you mean by deep cloning? I'd say that serialization is one possible implementation of deep cloning, what implementation do you mean?

Comment: @maaartinus I meant copying the data fields for every object in my big object in a way that if the later changed, the former will not be affected.. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but this is the description of *what* it does, not *how*. If you serialize and deserialize, you get a deep clone, too. Other way are to use reflection, to use `clone` recursively, to write a copy constructors, or whatever. The result of each of them will be a deep clone, but the performance will differ.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is expensive because it needs to analize object's class. Cloning is always faster.

Comment: would you please explain the *it needs to analyze object's class* thing.